# Clicking a button brings up a console for I/O

Tags: c#

this is my first time posting so I will be quick. I am very new to programming, I am currently starting with C#..

I am writing a form application that's basically a game. Think like one of those random .exe games you come across sometimes. Well anyway, I am determined to bang my head until it's built but I wanted to ask..

I am having trouble trying to find a way to bring up a console window via a button click event. The console would be used for IO.

Any help would be nice, and greatly appreciated.

Thank you all.

"EDIT" This question was marked as a duplicate, so I wanted to state why its different, the console window would come up and it would be used to talk to Orion, the exe program. Essentially IO, nothing more than that.

Comment: `Application.Run(new ConsoleApp());` just create the console app inside your current project and then run it.

Comment: what code do you have so far?

Comment: @vipersassassin that does not answer OP's question

Comment: @Phill3992 I have very little code save for 'this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkGray;' I am learning this stuff as I am working on the project. I had an earlier version of "Orion" but it got lost, this is Orion 2.0

Comment: I don't think you want a console window if I understand you correctly. I think you want a form where the user can type commands and see output??

Comment: Yesss @Ben That is what I need.

Comment: Make a form. Put a listbox on it for the output. Put a textbox on it for input. Put an OK button on it. When the user clicks OK you can process the input. Show output by adding lines to the listbox.